# How to combine all objects into one based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here is the scenario I am looking at:

I want to reduce these objects

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    totalAmount: 1500,
    date: '2021-01-01',
    vendor_id: 2,
    totalTransaction: 12,
    isRefund: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    totalAmount: 200,
    date: '2021-01-01',
    vendor_id: 2,
    totalTransaction: 2,
    isRefund: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    totalAmount: 200,
    date: '2021-01-01',
    vendor_id: 2,
    totalTransaction: 1,
    isRefund: true,
  },
];
```

and I found a solution that adds their values:

```
const deepMergeSum = (obj1, obj2) => {
  return Object.keys(obj1).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (typeof obj2[key] === 'object') {
      acc[key] = deepMergeSum(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
    } else if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key) && !isNaN(parseFloat(obj2[key]))) {
      acc[key] = obj1[key] + obj2[key]
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

const result = data.reduce((acc, obj) => (acc = deepMergeSum(acc, obj)));
const array = []
const newArray = [...array, result]
```

which results to:

```
const newArray = [
 {
   id: 6,
   totalAmount: 1900,
   date: '2021-01-012021-01-012021-01-01',
   vendor_id: 6,
   totalTransaction: 15
 }
]
```

And now my problem is I don't know yet how to work this around to have my expected output which if `isRefund` is true, it must be subtracted instead of being added, retain the `vendor_id` and also the concatenated `date` instead of only one entry date:

```
const newArray = [
 {
   id: 1(generate new id if possible),
   totalAmount: 1100,
   date: '2021-01-01',
   vendor_id: 2,
   totalTransaction: 15,
   isRefund: null(this can be removed if not applicable),
 },
];
```

I will accept and try to understand any better way or workaround for this. Thank you very much.

Comment: The easiest solution is to convert _"if isRefund is true"_ into an actual `if (...)` (isRefund is a `key`) and in that case subtract and in any other case (`else`) add the values -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Andreas I Tried adding your suggestion ealier like this:
    if (obj1["isRefund"] === true) {
      acc["totalAmount"] = obj1["totalAmount"] - obj2["totalAmount"]
    } else ....
And it only returned: 
   [ { totalAmount: 1900 } ]

Comment: @Andreas while using the obj2 instead of obj1 returned just the same as the result on the post since obj2 value is false.

Comment: `key` in _"(isRefund is a `key`)"_ is formatted as code for a reason ;)

Comment: @Andreas I'm really sorry I don't quite get how you wanted to mean it.

Comment: Do all your entries always have the same date? What should happen when they are different?

Comment: @trincot Ah yes. There will be an initial filtering of date so these suppose set of data will always be having the same dates

Comment: You say that if `isRefund` is true, the amount should be subtracted, but then for the example input I would expect -1100, not 1300. Can you clarify how you got 1300? Are you sure you want to *add* `vendor_id` values? That looks weird...

Comment: @trincot Oh no, Im really sorry I messed up my example. Ive edited the data correctly. Ah no, that's the other field I forgot to put in my problem. I also wanted to retain the `vendor_id`

Comment: You haven't shown your expected output

Comment: @pilchard the last code snippet is my expected output while the 2nd to the last was the current actual outpu for the solution I found.

Comment: I see, so just keep whichever `id` is encountered first and sum the amount and totalTransaction? This looks a lot like a basic `group by` grouped on vendorId  [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: @pilchard yes. It can be that way too if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Ill try this too. Thank you very much for the huge help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want custom behaviour for several fields, and don't need the recursive aspect of the merge, I would suggest you create a custom merge function, specific to your business logic:

```js
const data = [{id: 1,totalAmount: 1500,date: '2021-01-01',vendor_id: 2,totalTransaction: 12,isRefund: false,},{id: 2,totalAmount: 200,date: '2021-01-01',vendor_id: 2,totalTransaction: 2,isRefund: true,},{id: 3,totalAmount: 200,date: '2021-01-01',vendor_id: 2,totalTransaction: 1,isRefund: true,},];

function customMerge(a, b) {
    if (a.vendor_id !== b.vendor_id || a.date !== b.date) {
        throw "Both date and vendor_id must be the same";
    }
    return {
        id: Math.max(a.id, b.id),
        totalAmount: (a.isRefund ? -a.totalAmount : a.totalAmount) 
                   + (b.isRefund ? -b.totalAmount : b.totalAmount),
        date: a.date,
        vendor_id: a.vendor_id,
        totalTransaction: a.totalTransaction + b.totalTransaction
    };
}

const result = data.reduce(customMerge);
if (data.length > 1) result.id++; // Make id unique
console.log(result);
```

You could also reintroduce the `isRefund` property in the result for when the total amount turns out to be negative (only do this when `data.length > 1` as otherwise `result` is just the original single object in `data`):

```
result.isRefund = result.totalAmount < 0;
result.totalAmount = Math.abs(result.totalAmount);
```

### Distinct results for different dates and/or vendors

Then use a "dictionary" (plain object or `Map`) keyed by date/vendor combinations, each having an aggregating object as value.

To demonstrate, I added one more object in the data that has a different date and amount of 300:

```js
const data = [{id: 1,totalAmount: 1500,date: '2021-01-01',vendor_id: 2,totalTransaction: 12,isRefund: false,},{id: 2,totalAmount: 200,date: '2021-01-01',vendor_id: 2,totalTransaction: 2,isRefund: true,},{id: 3,totalAmount: 200,date: '2021-01-01',vendor_id: 2,totalTransaction: 1,isRefund: true,},{id: 4,totalAmount: 300,date: '2021-01-02',vendor_id: 2,totalTransaction: 1,isRefund: false,}];

function customMerge(acc, {id, date, vendor_id, totalAmount, totalTransaction, isRefund}) {
    let key = date + "_" + vendor_id;
    if (!(id <= acc.id)) acc.id = id;
    acc[key] ??= {
        date,
        vendor_id,
        totalAmount: 0,
        totalTransaction: 0
    };
    acc[key].totalAmount += isRefund ? -totalAmount : totalAmount;
    acc[key].totalTransaction += totalTransaction;
    return acc;
}

let {id, ...grouped} = data.reduce(customMerge, {});
let result = Object.values(grouped).map(item => Object.assign(item, { id: ++id }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you very much @trincot for the huge help. I'm really sorry but if I may ask, can this also be customized if there are multiple dates? since the filter was a ranged date picker. I answered your question earlier without even thinking of the other scenario

Comment: Sure it can, that's why asked about it in the first place.

Comment: Added a section to my answer about that.

Comment: Really. Thank you very very much for the huge help. Your 2nd solution was still beyond my current understanding but I will still try to understand it as I think it really will be helpful for my future encounter.

Answer (score 1):

it could be help, if you are looking for the same output, can add other checklist based on your requirement, for filtered date, logic would be little different but the output will be same.

```
const getTotalTranscation = () =>
  transctionLists.reduce((prev, current) => {
    const totalAmount = current.isRefund
      ? prev.totalAmount - current.totalAmount
      : prev.totalAmount + current.totalAmount;

    const totalTransaction = current.isRefund
      ? prev.totalTransaction - current.totalTransaction
      : prev.totalTransaction + current.totalTransaction;

    return {
      ...current,
      id: current.id + 1,
      totalAmount,
      totalTransaction,
      isRefund: totalAmount < 0,
    };
  });
```